# Zuul still routing to the instance of the application that are dead

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I started several instances of the same spring boot application on different ports.
On the other hand, I am using another application as a balancer(Eureka + Zuul proxy). I added annotations such are `@EnableEurekaServer` and `@EnableZuulProxy` on the balancer side.
I added properties to each instance:

```
eureka.instance.instance-id=application-name-[instance1]
eureka.instance.instance-id=application-name-[instance2]
```

In short, I did the setup and everything works as expected. But the problem starts when I **Kill** one of the instances. It takes 10-15 seconds while Eureka + Zuul understands that this instance is dead. If I continue calling my endpoint it works in round round-robin manner and still hits a dead instance on every second attempt.
I've googled(Or chatGPT) a lot but can't find a proper workaround.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.